# Запретить правилом в .htaccess доступ с других хостов

Tags: .htaccess

Хотелось бы с помощью `.htaccess` запретить доступ к сайту с других хостов. Нашёл в интернете следующий пример:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?my-site\.ru(/)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)\.my-site\.ru(/)?
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

Вопрос. Сторонний хост может отключить заголовок HTTP_REFERER. Как запретить доступ и для него?

Comment: Получается, что  вы хотите полностью закрыть доступ к сайту. С такими требованиями referer никогда не будет ссылаться на ваш сайт. я не прав?

Answer (score 1):

Если клиент не передаёт заголовок REFERER, отличить на сервере прямой заход на сайт (путём вбивания URL ругами в адресную строку браузера) от перехода по ссылке "с дргуого хоста" будет невозможно. Так что ответ на Ваш вопрос - никак.